# Can't remove tkinter root window

Tags: python, loops, class, tkinter

EDIT:
I realize that this question was ambiguous and incorrectly asked so I have tried to simplify.

I was having trouble trying to use a tkinter app to do multiple ploops due to not correctly destroying the window. My fix (which I'm quite sure is incorrect) was to create an integer loop, and nest my class within this:

```
for i in range(1, 1000):

if i >= 2:
    root.destroy()

class App(tkinter.Frame): *app code here*
```

to quit the app:

```
def OnButtonClick2(self):

        i = -1
        app.destroy()
        root.destroy()
        sys.exit()
```

otherwise:

```
i+=1
```

For some reason, if I instructed the app to destroy after the first iteration, it would leave a blank root window up and then when creating the app again the buttons would be unclickable and nested in a different window. This got rid of the problem, but I know it's not the correct solution.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I can certainly understand why somebody would downvote You've not really explained what your problem is, nor where in your code it lives. You've shown *a lot* of code (which is certainly better than no code at all, but not nearly as good as a smaller amount). Please try to shrink it down to a [mcve], that is, the smallest amount of code that can demonstrate the issue. And explain what that issue is, so we can have some idea of what you're trying to do and how you're running into trouble before we even start reading the code!

Comment: Expanding on @Blckknght's answer, you're essentially trying to restart a tkinter app. What the app actually does is not relevant at all to the question. You can leave only the bare minimum, "hello world" app, try to restart it, and tell us about your efforts. Then, we can point you in the right direction. I hope you don't expect any of us to volunteer to read 156 lines of code and debug your application for you.

Comment: @roeen30 I certainly don't, and thanks for the input.
I've tried to put a __call__ function before the __init__ , but I don't think that I was writing it correctly.
I'm bad with the terminology and I'm still very new, so I don't quite know how to explain what else I've tried. I've also just tried to directly reference an instance after mail.Display(True) so that when the email window is gone it continues. That didn't work either.

Please see my edits and let me know if that's more acceptable.

Comment: @Blckknght thanks for the input. Please see edits.

Comment: This is better but I still don't understand enough of what's going on. Where does the second code sample fit with the tkinter app? Additionally, please post the code of everything you tried so far.

Comment: @roeen30 I deleted the 2nd sample as it was useless. I posted what I have tried for the code I remember. I also tried to make the entire thing a function (I'm sure that's completely wrong) and then call the function and that didn't work.

Comment: Why is making it all a function is wrong? It was what I was about to suggest

Comment: @roeen30 I mean I don’t actually know enough to say that that’s wrong. I suppose I just don’t know how to nest the class within a function.

Comment: I can think of two options. Either arrange the logic you wish to repeat as a class method or put everything under `if __name__ == '__main__'` in a function. Whether a method or a function, call it in a loop. There's no need to put the class definition itself in a function.

Comment: @roeen30 thank you, I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Posting as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either arrange the logic you wish to repeat as a class method or put everything under if `__name__ == '__main__'` in a function. Whether a method or a function, call it in a loop.